# find all files with .sh .cpp .c extension and copy them to a directory in my desktop, if there is a file with the same name, rename it

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

I have to copy all files with .sh .cpp .c extensions to a directory at my desktop and rename the files with the same name.
If I have two files named hello.cpp, change the name to hello1.cpp.

I already tried this:

```
find /root \ (-name *.cpp -o -name *.sh \) -exec cp {} /root/Desktop/myNewDir \;
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
cp: '/root/Desktop/mynewDir/hello.cpp' and '/root/Desktop/myNewDir/hello.cpp' are the same file
```

Comment: Why are you putting parens there, and why aren't you escaping one of them properly?

Comment: The error tells you you're copying the files over themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are traversing recursively on `/root` and `find`-ing the same file to copy over it.

If you want to stick to recursion, then `-prune` `/root/Desktop/myNewDir/` from `find`'s recursion:

```
find /root/ -type d -name /root/Desktop/myNewDir/ -prune -o -type f \
     \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.sh' \) -exec cp --backup=numbered 
        -t /root/Desktop/myNewDir/ {} +
```

If you don't want recursion, this gets very easy:

```
find /root/ -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.sh' \) \
    -exec cp -t /root/Desktop/myNewDir/ {} +
```